# How to remove one page of windows phone backstack?

Tags: windows-phone-7

My Backstack has four pages,A,B,C,D.Now I just want to remove D Page from my app backstack when I have navigated to the page E.I search the Google and find some guys use  `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` to finish.However it doesn't fit me,it will remove all the page of my app backstack.:)

Answer (score 6):

`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` removes only the last entry from the backstack, so it should fit your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

> **This method is used to remove the most recent entry from the back stack**, or throws an InvalidOperationException if there are no more entries to remove. **If you want to remove more than one item, you call this method multiple times**.