# Windows phone extended splash back navigation

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8, splash-screen, back

I created a extended splash screen for my windows phone app, but now everytime I press back on the home page it reloads the extended splashscreen. Is it possible to remove it from the navigation stack and let the app execute the application_closing event?

code for splash:

```
public partial class ExtendedSplashScreen : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ExtendedSplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Call MainPage from ExtendedSplashScreen after some delay            
        Splash_Screen();
    }

    async void Splash_Screen()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); // set your desired delay            
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Screens/HomeScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative));    
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove one page of windows phone backstack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510798/how-to-remove-one-page-of-windows-phone-backstack)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can remove it from back stack, try this

`int a = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
            while (a > 0)
            {
                this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                a = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
            }` 
Here **a > 0** used because nothing should be befour home page.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the HomeScreen.xaml.cs file:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
    {
        this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

It will clean the backstack, so that the app exits when pressing the back button.